# Word or expression to describe the tendency that one have to believe that everyone is like them or the act of doing it

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

This is something I noticed among some people I discuss with. When some opinion relative subjects are raised, they tend to imply that, according to their "normality", everyone is behaving like them or have the same opinions on the matters as they do.

The following is an example of a conversation

> Acquaintance: We prefer *food A*. *Food A* is much better than *food
> B* which is clearly more expensive and not nearly as good.
>
> Me (the tendency): Please, could you stop being (a)/(an) ____? Not everyone have all have the same taste, hobbies and point of views as you do.

One expression I thought about which kinda describes the act of doing that is *picturing one self in the others*, but it isn't exactly what I am looking for, as it is closer to a parent seeing one self in their child.

I also thought about *enforcing your point of view*, but that is closer to forcibly convincing your correspondent during an argument.

Comment: [**Projecting:**](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/projecting) to wrongly imagine that someone else is feeling a particular emotion or desire when in fact it is you who feels this way?

Comment: Your example is mild, not self-centered. Can you exaggerate so we understand?

Comment: I think the proper term is "human".

Comment: @YosefBaskin Currently trying to find an appropriate exaggerated example, but so far I only found some controversial ones (which I would like to avoid posting), because of which I'm also considering to delete the question.

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul In the end, I think "Projecting" was the most appropriate word for what I wanted to say.

Answer (score 2):

Egocentrism: the inability to differentiate between self and other. More specifically, it is the inability to untangle subjective schemas from objective reality and an inability to accurately assume or understand any perspective other than one's own.

Comment: We require proper attribution in all cases on this site. And Wikipedia isn't normally regarded as an authoritative source.